# Pathname or word too long in Cshell

Tags: shell, shell-script, path, csh

I am using cshell. And I know that there is a limit of 1024 character while setting path. But I have many path variables which I need to set. So, it is exceeding 1024 characters and I am getting an error.
Can you tell me some workaround ?
For some personal reason I need to use cshell as of now.

```
~> source .cshrc
Pathname or word too long.
```

Comment: A good read: Csh programming (... and use!) considered harmful : https://harmful.cat-v.org/software/csh

Comment: try: `.  ./.cshrc`  # careful, reading .cshrc mutiple time may end up doing multiple times things that you don't want. For exemple add something to $PATH multiple times?